# Does the code now work for reading letters from the gmail javax library?

Tags: android, gmail

I found many examples of accessing gmail using the Java library, but I can not start it.
There were doubts, because all the examples are old.

```
`Properties props2 = new Properties();
    props2.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", mailServer);
    props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
    props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", 
"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    imapSession = Session.getInstance(props2);
}   
public void getInboxMails() throws MessagingException {
    store = imapSession.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect(mailServer, account.username, account.password);`
```

Comment: Did it work when you tried it?

Comment: No, that's the question

Comment: In your account settings - unsafe apps are allowed